# When does $\int_0^{0.5} x^{n-5000}(\log(x))^{-50}dx$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Intuitively looks like $\log$ doesn't really influence convergence so much and I'd guess that answer is something like $n\geq 4999$, but I'm having trouble formalizing that.

Well, for $n=4999$ we have $\int_0^{0.5} \frac{1}{x (\log(x))^{50}} dx$ and substitution $y=\log(x)$ would prove convergence. For $n \geq 5000$ convergence is obvious.

Thank you.

Comment: A partial answer: Setting $1/\log(0)=0$, observe that $(\log(x))^{-50}$ is continuous and positive on $[0,0.5]$. Also, $x^N$ doesn't change sign on $[0,0.5]$. By the First Mean Value Theorem for Integrals,
$$
\int _{0}^{0.5} x^{n-5000}(\log(x))^{-50}\,dx = (\log(c))^{-50}\int _{0}^{0.5} x^{n-5000}\,dx ,
$$for some $c\in (0,0.5)$. Then we're at a usual $p$-integral, whence we get convergence for $n>4999$.

At $n=4999$ you can substitute and get convergence, as you mentioned. But I think this might not be the whole story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have it now. Put $x=e^{-z}$, $dx=-e^{-z}\,dz$. Then
$$
\int _0^{1/2} x^{n-5000}(\log(x))^{-50}\,dx = \int _{\log(2)}^{\infty} e^{(4999-n) z} z^{-50}\,dz
$$Clearly if $n\geq 4999$ this converges (power rule if $n=4999$, direct comparison to $z^{-50}$ if $n>4999$). But if $n<4999$ then the integral can't converge because the exponential term dominates the power. So we get convergence exactly when $n\geq 4999$.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Comment: took me long enough...